# Hibernate bidirectional OneToOne join fetch producing n+1 queries

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Given the following demo classes:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Child child;

    ...
}

@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Parent parent;

    ...
}
```

The following HQL statement

```
SELECT p FROM Parent AS p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.child
```

loads all Parent entities with a single query

```
    select
        parent0_.id as id1_1_0_,
        child1_.id as id1_0_1_,
        child1_.parent_id as parent_i2_0_1_ 
    from
        Parent parent0_ 
    left outer join
        Child child1_ 
            on parent0_.id=child1_.parent_id
```

However, fetching the Child entities with the following HQL:

```
SELECT c FROM Child AS c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.parent
```

leads to n+1 queries loading fields redundantly:

```
    select
        child0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        parent1_.id as id1_1_1_,
        child0_.parent_id as parent_i2_0_0_ 
    from
        Child child0_ 
    left outer join
        Parent parent1_ 
            on child0_.parent_id=parent1_.id

    select
        child0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        child0_.parent_id as parent_i2_0_0_ 
    from
        Child child0_ 
    where
        child0_.parent_id=?

    ...
```

Why does fetching from the child's side cause this issue?

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: 5.2.13, but also reproducible with the latest version (5.4.18)